# Get Javascript below fixed div

Tags: javascript, css

http://www.haymsalomonhome.com/recovery.html

The blue button on the far right is a fixed `div`. How can I get it to float ABOVE the Javascript slideshow? `z-index` does not work in this case...

On a page that has just an image with no Javascript, the fixed button does float above it:

http://www.haymsalomonhome.com/cultural.html

Comment: I see that you fixed it, please accept one of the answers, the one that suits you best!

Answer (score 0):

Try `z-index:9999` it should work.
The slideshow has `z-index:999` so it won't work it below 999

Answer (score 0):

Your z-index is too low the slide show divs have z-index of 999 and 1000 just increace the z-index higher.

Answer (score 0):

This works fine:

```
#fadeshow1 {
z-index: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you setting the z-index high enough?  The z-index on the slideshow elements are 999 and 1000.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use this:

```
#fixed-div {
    position: fixed;
    top: 320px;
    right: 0px;
    width: 123px;
    height: 20px;
    z-index: 9999;
}
```

Because the slideshow has `z-index:999`, so `z-index:999;` on `#fixed-div` won't workout.